# Class C Module is not an Angular module

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular-library

I have created an angular library and for testing i included it is as a npm dependency in test angular project.
when i add the module (exported from lib) to app.module imports i am getting error as Class C is not an Angular module . Please help

structure is like

```
Projects
 customLibrary
   lib
    index.ts (having reference to all folders)
    customModule.ts
 public-api.ts (export * from './lib';)
```

tried refering to the link but couldn't solve the issue 
[Angular class is not an Angular module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120032/angular-class-is-not-an-angular-module)

Comment: Can you share your codes?

Comment: @shofol it works if i start from a fresh library but i am migrating some existing code base into a library and cant share the code base here.