# Cannot use *ngFor in library

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular-directive

I have created an Angular library using:

1. ng new my-workspace --create-application=false
2. cd my-workspace
3. ng generate library my-lib

The library works. However when I modify the template to use *ngFor as follows:

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  my-lib works!
</div>
```

I get an error:

> No directive is matched on attribute ngFor

I have had no success with various suggestions found so far. If you know how to get a new clean library configured to use directives such as *ngFor I would greatly appreciate your advice.
I have created the library with both Angular 8 and 9 with the result being the same.

Kind regards

Sean

Comment: Have you tried this fix too: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11454#issuecomment-402693306?

Comment: @Sean Make sure that your variable is stateless

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have been down these paths without success. Are you able to build a library following the same steps as me and get it to work? It should be simple ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Please import CommonModule inside your custom module. After that include it inside the imports array.

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

imports: [
  CommonModule
]
```

Comment: I have updated my-lib.module.ts as suggested. I then get an error of "Class CommonModule is not an Angular module"
Have you built a fresh library and tried this? I am curious to know if this "just me" or if anyone following the steps I did would get the same result.

Comment: This was the general reason why *ngFor was not working I have not created a fresh library, this link is now related to your new issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120032/angular-class-is-not-an-angular-module

Comment: In the link you provided there appeared to be no problem importing CommonModule. The post addresses an issue with using a library in a separate project. I could not see anything that helps with my issue. If I have missed something then please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Oops, I was getting this error because I was iterating with `in` instead of `of`.

So change:

`<li *ngFor="let thing in things"`

to:

`<li *ngFor="let thing of things"`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I now have code that compiles and runs fine. However I am still getting errors in the IDE (Webstorm).
The solution was to import CommonModule and then ignore the errors...
I will follow up with JetBrains re possible Webstorm issue.

The solution from JetBrains to remove the errors was to change "peerDependencies" to "devDependencies" in the library's package.json file, then run npm install.
This worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can always switch to ng-template

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index">
  my-lib works!
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your Angular-CLI which is not properly installed. Even out of curiosity, I have followed the exact steps told by you in your question and found out that even if you will resolve this error by yourself, you will again receive trail of errors. So, its your CLI which is causing the issue. Try uninstalling Angular-CLI first and follow below steps

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm cache verify or npm cache verify --force
```

And than re-install

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```